# Is Trump's election the first successful presidential election campaign with a female campaign manager?

Tags: united-states, politics, gender, donald-trump

From a [tweet](https://twitter.com/SebastianSanRM/status/797436778634309634) with over six thousand retweets, also retweeted by [Nazí Paikidze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naz%C3%AD_Paikidze), International Master (IM) and Woman Grandmaster (WGM):

> The first woman in American history to successfully manage a presidential campaign was Trump's campaign manager

Assuming that "successfully manage" means managing a presedential campaign that resulted in that candidate's election, is Trump's election campaign the first successful US presidential campaign with a female campaign manager?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Obama's 2012 campaign: Jim Messina
- Obama's 2008: David Plouffe
- G.W. Bush 2004: Ken Mehlman
- G.W. Bush 2000: Joe Allbaugh
- Clinton (1996): James Carville
- Clinton (1992): David Wilhelm
- George H. W. Bush (1988): Lee Atwater
- Ronald Reagan (1984): Ed Rollins
- Ronald Reagan (1980): William J. Casey
- Jimmy Carter (1976): [Robert Strauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_S._Strauss)
- Richard Nixon (1972): [John Mitchell / Clark MacGregor](http://www.npr.org/sections/politicaljunkie/2009/07/on_this_day_in_1972_john_mitch.html)

So, since at least 1972, all males

Source: Wiki pages for all of them/campaigns.

Comment: That answer is incomplete, what about all other campaigns?

Comment: @daraos Assuming that "The arc of the moral universe is long, but it bends towards justice", more recent election campaigns are more likely to be equal opportunity in their choice of campaign managers than older election campaigns.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I don't think that that is an assumption that always holds. Here are some more managers (source: wiki): Clinton (1996): James Carville, Clinton (1992): David Wilhelm, George H. W. Bush (1988): Lee Atwater, Ronald Reagan (1984): Ed Rollins, Ronald Reagan (1980): William J. Casey. Again all male, but still not really enough to prove or disprove the claim.

Comment: @tim - Thanks for the find! I made the answer CW, since people added more data to it than I did, by now.

Comment: (Hamilton Jordan's page indicates he ran Carter's gubernatorial campaign, but was only a "key advisor" for the '76 Presidential race. Strauss ran the '76 race.)